# Why jython doesn't import External Jar?

Tags: java, jython-2.7

I'm working on Jython, but I have a big problem, Jython doesn't import external jar file

This is the error:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('home/francesco/documents/jars/spigot.jar')
>>> from org.bukkit import *
    Traceback (most recent call last):File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    ImportError: No module named bukkit
```

What can I do to resolve it?

Jython version = 2.7.0

Comment: For starters, that path looks questionable; it's relative.

Comment: I've tried with other path and other jars, but didn't work

Comment: Check your path properly that you are passing to `sys.path.append()`. Also please check if `org` folder exists inside `spigot.jar`. See the errors and try to rectify.

Comment: This does not work in 2.7.2 as well I tried this under Windows with absolute paths and the result is the same